# How do I get the codes still running on a remote host when I close JetBrain Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, remote-debugging

I use JetBrain Pycharm to run codes on remote hosts. Because my codes need to run for a long time, I want to temporarily turn off JetBrain Pycharm and let the codes still run on the remote host. Untill the codes are executed, I opene pycharm to see the results on the remote host.

How do I get the codes still running on a remote host when I close JetBrain Pycharm? I guess that I should click the "Disconnect", but it does not work as I think.

**First, I turn on Pycharm and let the codes run on a remote host.**
[image]

**Secondly, I want to temporarily turn off JetBrain Pycharm and let the codes still run on the remote host. I try to click on "Disconnect".**
[image]

**Thirdly, I turn on pycharm again to see if the code is still running. However, it may not work as I think.**
[image]

So, How do I get the codes still running on a remote host when I close JetBrain Pycharm? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should click on disconnet and it will not terminate it.

Comment: I click on "Disconnect" to turn off Pycharm, and then I turn on Pycharm again, I find that the codes do not show any signs of being executed.

Comment: There are two things, one disconnecting Pycharm and then disconnecting from the remote host, I don't know how you are executing things but if it is a command line or process you need to use tools suchas a nohup to send the process to the background., might be better to run it via command line with something like  nohup python run.py arg1 arg2 &